# How to implement data I have to svmtrain() function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, svm

I have to write a script using MATLAB which will classify my data.

My data consists of 1051 web pages (rows) and 11000+ words (columns). I am holding the word occurences in the matrix for each page. The first 230 rows are about computer science course (to be labeled with +1) and remaining 821 are not (to be labeled with -1). I am going to label few part of these rows (say 30 rows) by myself. Then SVM will label the remaining unlabeled rows.

I have found that I could solve my problem using MATLAB's `svmtrain()` and `svmclassify()` methods. First I need to create `SVMStruct`.

```
SVMStruct = svmtrain(Training,Group)
```

Then I need to use

```
Group = svmclassify(SVMStruct,Sample)
```

But the point that I do not know what `Training` and `Group`  are. For `Group` [Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/svmtrain.html) says:

> Grouping variable, which can be a categorical, numeric, or logical
>   vector, a cell vector of strings, or a character matrix with each row
>   representing a class label. Each element of Group specifies the group
>   of the corresponding row of Training. Group should divide Training
>   into two groups. Group has the same number of elements as there are
>   rows in Training. svmtrain treats each NaN, empty string, or
>   'undefined' in Group as a missing value, and ignores the corresponding
>   row of Training.

And for `Training` it is said that:

> Matrix of training data, where each row corresponds to an observation
>   or replicate, and each column corresponds to a feature or variable.
>   svmtrain treats NaNs or empty strings in Training as missing values
>   and ignores the corresponding rows of Group.

I want to know how I can adopt my data to `Training` and `Group`? I need (at least) a little code sample.

**EDIT**

What I did not understand is that in order to have `SVMStruct` I have to run

```
SVMStruct = svmtrain(Training, Group);
```

and in order to have Group I have to run

```
Group = svmclassify(SVMStruct,Sample);
```

Also I still did not get what `Sample` should be like?

I am confused.

Answer (score 2):

`Training` would be a matrix with 1051 rows (the webpages/training instances) and 11000 columns (the features/words). I'm assuming you want to test for the existence of each word on a webpage? In this case you could make the entry of the matrix a `1` if the word exists for a given webpage and a `0` if not.

You could initialize the matrix with `Training = zeros(1051,11000);` but filling the entries would be up to you, presumably done with some other code you've written.

`Group` is a 1-D column vector with one entry for every training instance (webpage) than tells you which of two classes the webpage belongs to. In your case you would make the first 230 entries a "+1" for computer science and the remaining  821 entries a "-1" for not.

```
Group = zeros(1051,1);  % gives you a matrix of zeros with 1051 rows and 1 column
Group(1:230) = 1;       % set first 230 entries to +1
Group(231:end) = -1;    % set the rest to -1
```

Comment: `svmtrain()` is the learning step in your algorithm. `Training` is your training data and `Group` are the labels for that training data. The resulting `SVMstruct` is a collection of parameters you learned all stored under one name (you see can what it contains by double clicking on it in the workspace window). The `SVMclassify()` is where you put in _unlabelled_ data called `Sample` for your algorithm to classify. `svmclassify()` puts `Sample` into your model and outputs the (hopefully correct) labels `Group`, which is a _different_ `Group` than the first one.

Comment: Please can you help me here? thank you a lot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65449934/multi-class-svm-one-vs-one-always-giving-the-same-label